# Protect script from hacking (reading directories, modifying files)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to write script, that will run all my tests automatically and check for failures, smth like that (simply run test with "ruby file.rb" and parsing output):

```
def failures?(test_file)
  io = IO.popen("ruby #{test_file}")
  log = io.readlines
  io.close

  # parsing output for failures "1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors"
  log.last.split(',').select{ |s| s =~ /failures/ }.first[/\d+/] != "0"
end

puts failures?("test.rb")
```

But someone can easily place some malicious code in "test_file" and crush everything:

```
Dir.glob("*")
Dir.mkdir("HACK_DIR")
File.delete("some_file")
```

What is the way to protect ruby script from such hacking?

Comment: Different OSes have different permission models.  Which OS are you using?

Comment: I can only repeat: Don't follow the advise given in the accepted answer if you want to be safe. You will get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to that but using the concept of a "sandbox".

First you create a test user that has no permissions to any of your OS files (of course not to your test files either).

Your testing system will first copy the whole tests root folder to a sandbox (created at a temp location for example), give the testing user permission to this sandbox and execute the tests as the test user.

So, the tests execution file creation/modification/deletion is restricted to this sandbox. Also, you can analyse later on all the tests post-mortem data that was left in this sandbox.

I did this easily in linux creating folders on the /tmp dir and using a special user called "tester".

Hope this helps.

Comment: What you describe is not a sandbox. The code has still reading permissions to system files like `/etc/passwd` or configuration files with potentially sensitive data in them. Also, the code can still connect itself to the internet and execute commands, for example to spawn a reverse shell which a malicious human being could use to try and exploit your server. This cannot be recommended. At least use a chroot, or even better, `$SAFE` in combination with a Ruby sandbox solution in combination with a RBAC system or even a virtual machine.

Comment: Quite logical solution, thanx! I will try to implement smth like this by means of Ruby.

Comment: Found a couple of presentations about sandboxing in Ruby:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XxCOYco3Eg
http://www.bestechvideos.com/2009/06/04/pivotal-labs-talks-playing-with-fire-running-uploaded-ruby-code-in-a-sandbox

Comment: You are completely right Niklas. My intention on my code was not against malicious use of testing, but just against a test that might not be that well written and unwilling damage some other testing files. I did write "sandbox" and not directly sandbox because of that. I don't mean no damage at all, rather no unintentional damage cause of small mistakes.